# Rails Validation Inclusion dynamically

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, validation

```
class A
  include ActiveModel::Validations
  attr_reader :operator
  def initialize(operator)
    @operator = operator
    validates_inclusion_of :operator, in => operators
  end

  def operators
    ....
  end
end
```

Here I want to validate the operator for inclusion_of dynamically. the method operators returns an array of operators which is dynamic.

The above code is not working. How can I implement the validation dynamically?
r

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You may try:

```
def initialize(operator)
  self.class.class_eval do
    validates_inclusion_of :operator, :in => operators
  end
end
```

although I don't understand why can't you just define it at the class level. Note that argument to :in can be a lambda, for details refer to: http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveModel/Validations/HelperMethods/validates_inclusion_of

Comment: Thanks. I'll check this. The method `operatos` picks the operators dynamically according to the object, that is why I did not put it class level.

Comment: Yes, and in that case you can use the lambda for :in.